# How to pass special characeters while submitting a job in data proc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-submit

i am trying to pass a url as key value pair in data proc submit job, how ever this url has "=" in it , so its not considering the later part after "="

how do i pass whole url as key value pair?/

Arguments:

```
master=yarn
topic.name=testing_topic
url.main="https://test-server.tst-testing.us.net/test_path/gen?genKey=genKeyValue"
```

when i pass this to program

url.main is coming up as

```
"https://test-server.tst-testing.us.net/test_path/gen?genKey"
```

Comment: Can you show your command? How are you submitting the job? For example, are you using gcloud?